# How does this:Use backet to achieve if statement in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement

I saw this usage of Python, which is very clean, but I don't really understand this usage, and can't search any useful explanation about it either.

1. This is the normal method:

   ```
   if a < 0:
       b = 2 * a
   else:
       b = 3 * a
   ```
2. And this realizes the same purpose:

   ```
   b = a * (3,2) [a<0]
   ```

Can someone tell me  **Where does the official documentation say something about the above ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b = a * (3,2) [a<0]`

`a<0` is a condition returning `true or false` i.e. `1/0`

`(3,2)` is a tuple with `3` and `2` as elements

if the condition is `true` statement will be indexing the element at index `1`  else it will indexing to element `0`

like

```
In [33]: (3,2)[0]
Out[33]: 3

In [34]: (3,2)[1]
Out[34]: 2
```

The condition results in `0` or `1` because In python `True means 1` and `False means 0`

```
In [35]: True == 1
Out[35]: True

In [36]: False == 0
Out[36]: True
```

Comment: Can give the address of offical docs about this ?TKS your answer

Comment: i doubt if there a official doc about this, this is all about combining what you know about `tuples` and `conditional` statements, this is not the standard way to do this but it is one of the ways, and even if there would be a doc somewhere, it would only refer of the standard method of `if-else`

Answer (score 2):

Use the second option for golfing purposes only. The docs really don't say much about this syntax, but [*The Zen of Python*](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) does state that 'Simple is better than complex', and that 'Readability counts'. You should use the first option.

You could also use Python's *ternary operator*:

```
b = a*(2 if a < 0 else 3)
```

Comment: golfed would be more like `b=a*(3-(a<0))`